# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "puppeteer". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: puppeteer, openai-api

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Aryaa</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>CHATGpt</h1>

 <div id="chat-container">
    <div id="chat-log"></div>
    <input type="text" id="user-input" placeholder="Enter your message...." autofocus />
    <button id="send-button">Send</button>
 </div>

</body>
<script type="module" src="./aryaa.mjs"></script>
<script >
        import { puppeteer } from "./aryaa.mjs"
        console.log(puppeteer)
     </script>
</html>
```

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";
const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body></body></html>');
const document = dom.window.document;
(async () => {
  // Launch a headless browser
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

 
  await browser.close();
})();
import axios from 'axios';

const chatLog = document.getElementById('chat-log');
const userInput = document.getElementById('user-input');
const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-button');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if (sendButton) {
    sendButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
      const userMessage = userInput.value;
      try {
        const response = await generateResponse(userMessage);
        displayToUser(response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error);
      }
    });
  }
});

async function generateResponse(prompt) {
    


  const apiKey = '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';
  const apiUrl = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions';
  const configuration = new Configuration({
    organization: "org-5aDD3n2wdcAcGVxBiZAhKSg0",
    apiKey: process.env.apiKey,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
const response = await openai.listEngines();

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(apiUrl,{
   "id":"chatcmpl-abc123",
   "object":"chat.completion",
   "created":1677858242,
   "model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301",
   "usage":{
      "prompt_tokens":13,
      "completion_tokens":7,
      "total_tokens":20
   },
   "choices":[
      {
         "message":{
            "role":"assistant",
            "content":"\n\nThis is a test!"
         },
         "finish_reason":"stop",
         "index":0
      }
   ],
      messages: [
        { role: 'system', content: 'You are a helpful assistant.' },
        { role: 'user', content: prompt }
      ],
    }, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${apiKey}',
      },
    });

    const data = response.data;
    return data.choices[0].text.trim();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Failed to generate a response: ' + error.message);
  }
}

 async function displayToUser(message) {
  console.log(message); // Modify this function to display the message to the user in your desired way
}

async function main() {
  const userQuestion = "What is e2ndopinion?";
  try {
    const response = await generateResponse(userQuestion);
    if (response.includes('e2ndopinion')) {
      displayToUser(response);
    } else {
      const response = await generateResponse(userQuestion);
      displayToUser(response);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
  }
}

main();
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "puppeteer".
> Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

This is the html code is used

I don't understand how to fix this error.

I want that when the user enter anything in the input box it replies in the console. This is openai API.